# Can i create more than one AppAsset.php files for different views?

Tags: php, yii2

I am using AppAsset.php file for registering & using CSS & JS files for the opening page of my webapp. Along with that i have another section that has different JS & CSS files which are common throughout the section. I have to register them as they are common. Is it best practice to create another AppAsset.php (With diff. name) & make it work instead of using registerJsFile() & registerCssFile() method???.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using AppAsset.php file for registering & using CSS & JS files
>   for the opening page of my webapp.

By default `AppAsset` is used for all application views and registered in main layout. So it's not only for opening page.

> Along with that i have another section that has different JS & CSS
>   files which are common throughout the section. I have to register them
>   as they are common.

Just create separate `AssetBundle` for these JS and CSS files and register it in this specific section.

You can create as many assets as you want and use it anywhere you want.

Managing assets is covered in [this section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) of official documentation.

> Is it best practice to create another AppAsset.php (With diff. name) &
>   make it work instead of using registerJsFile() & registerCssFile()
>   method???.

Definitely yes. It's even mentioned in [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#registering-asset-bundles):

> As was mentioned earlier it's preferred to use asset bundles instead
>   of using CSS and JavaScript directly.

Dependencies is the key feature of assets, otherwise you should manually set order of included files.

Comment: baseUrl i came to know why it is used. But i didn't get where basePath = @webroot points to

Comment: It's alias of directory with entry script (index.php). https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Application.php#L60

Comment: For files under web-accessible directory use $basePath, if they are outside of it - $sourcePath.

Comment: how would you unregister / de-attach AppAsset bundle (or assets from AppAsset) to be included in a certain view?

Comment: I think it's better to separate such assets to different asset bundles.